# Managing Multiple Magento Stores

Tags: magento-1.9

Hey guys so I am just wondering what would be the best way to manage multiple stores on one server.

So I have noticed that it is becoming very hard to keep updating all of my sites with changes. Most of the sites use exactly the same setup such as the same admin settings.

When I want to make a change to all of my sites this becomes an issue because if I want to update my Magento version on all of my stores I need to do this manually for each one.

Is there a way to possibly make all of these sites run off the same core code? I do not want to share the same catalog with each store though.

Any help on tips for running multiple stores would be great.

Thanks, Nick

Comment: So, just to clarify, you have multiple Magento Platforms installed separately(seperate folders) on different domains/subdomains but only on 1 server? Or multiple store views on 1 Magento Platform on 1 server?

Comment: It's possible that you could run all three sites off the same code, maybe symlink the code and leave the var and media folders separately, but it could be a pain in the ass to manage. You might be better to work out an automated way of making changes to all instances at once (a script of sorts)